# C# MongoDB Driver Queryable Contains returns document is not supported

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

Im following the MongoDB Driver [documentantion](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/languages/csharp/using-linq-query-mongodb-dotnet-core-application/) to use LINQ, and any kind of *Contains* conditions are returning "[Document] is not supported", even though it has several examples in the documentation:

```
var results = from movie in moviesCollection.AsQueryable()
              where movie.Cast.Contains("Michael Keaton")
              select new { movie.Title, movie.Plot };
```

My code:

```
var filter = "Test Words";
var data = collection.AsQueryable()
                     .Where(p=> filter.Split(" ").Contains(p.Name))
                     .ToList();
```

I also tried the opposite:

```
var data = collection.AsQueryable()
                     .Where(p=> p.Name.Contains("Test"))
                     .ToList();
```

Yet, any attempt returns "document is not supported".
Anyone has any clue why this is happening?

Comment: Are you using the latest driver?

Comment: Im using 2.17.1.

Comment: try using linq3: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/reference/driver/crud/linq3/

Comment: see also `Unsupported LINQ or Builder expressions`: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.17/frequently_encountered_issues/